# Why does vim not highlighting leading and trailing spaces?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, regular-expression

I want trailing and leading whitespaces to be highlighted by vim. I created a ~/.vimrc file and appended this:

```
" highlight trailing and leading whitespaces
highlight TrailingWhitespaces ctermbg=red
match TrailingWhitespaces /\s\s*$/
highlight LeadingWhitespaces ctermbg=red
match LeadingWhitespaces /^\s\s*/
```

For some reason `/\s+$/` and `/^\s+/`  didn't work at all it matched 
the `+` literally - i.e. `/\s\+$/`

Furthermore,  only the first one, Trailing- or LeadingWhitespaces is being applied:
[image]

As you can see, leading whitespaces are highlighted but trailing ones are not. Once I put the `LeadingWhitespaces` at the top, only trailing whitespaces are highlighted:

[image]

What am I not doing right?

I don't think there is a conflict with any other options in my ~/.vimrc file but just in case, [here is the whole file](https://pastebucket.com/565899).

Comment: You can only have one `:match` at a time. Use `:2match` for the second match, or combine the two regular expressions.

Comment: Use `listchars` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue with your code is that you can only have one `:match` at a time, so your second call overwrites your first call. (See `:help :match` — a few paragraphs down.)

Vim provides a `:2match` command for the purpose of highlighting a second pattern:

```
match TrailingWhitespaces /\s\s*$/
2match LeadingWhitespaces /^\s\s*/
```

Alternatively, you could use the `matchadd()` function, or (ab)use the `:syntax` highlighting to provide multiple regular expressions:

```
syntax match TrailingWhitespaces /\s\s*$/
syntax match LeadingWhitespaces /^\s\s*/
```

Or you could combine the two regular expressions with `\|`: (See `:help /\|`.)

```
match TrailingAndLeadingWhitespaces /\s\s*$\|^\s\s*/
```

A couple of other notes:

1. Even with two match commands, you don't really need two highlight *groups*, since you're using the same colour for both matches.
2. Unless you're using a `very magic` search (see `:help /\v`) then `+` does indeed match a literal plus character. You need to use `\+` to match "one or more of the preceding atom". You appear to have figured this out though, because you actually include a working regular expression in your question: `/\s\+$/`, so I'm not sure why you didn't use this in your matches?